# How to get back auto-completion after misspelling a method name in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, autosuggest, misspelling

When I am coding Java in Eclipse I like the auto-completion feature. With that I mean the popup with method-names that comes when you start typing in a method name for an object. *Or maybe it's called something different, i.e. method-suggestions?*

But the popup is hidden if I misspells a method name, and it doesn't come back if I delete the misspelled part of the method name. Is there any way to get back the popup after a misspelling without starting to type in the hole method name again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ (Blank). For a complete list of keyboard shortcuts have a look in the eclipse "Preferences" and there "General/Keys".

Answer (score 2):

You should also check out Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist. You'll be able to select how it acts; things like if you use it in the middle of a word should it insert or overwrite, should it show deprecated methods, the delay before it automatically appears, and it can even (try to) guess your method parameters based on the variables in the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're after the Ctrl-Space keyboard shortcut.

(In Eclipse this is called Content Assist. In Visual Studio it's called IntelliSense.)